# OKHttpClient - can't connect

Tags: android, kotlin, build, retrofit2, okhttp

these are all of my code:
model class like:

```
data class User(
var phone: String,
var password: String
```

)

i named Interface class -->"APIS" :

```
interface APIS {
@GET("id")
fun getCustomer(@Query("id") id: String
): retrofit2.Call<Customer>

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
fun sentUser(
    @Field("phone") phone: String?,
    @Field("password") password: String?
): retrofit2.Call<User>

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("id_address") 
fun updateAddress(
    @Field("lat") lat: String?,
    @Field("long") lng: String?
): retrofit2.Call<Address>
```

}

after that i write an object as follow :

object ClientRetrofit {
private const val BASE_URL = "https://shahrman.ioplus.ir/api/peyk/"

```
private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder() .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()

fun <T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T {
    return retrofit.create(service)
}
```

}

after that MainActivity class is :

```
val request = ClientRetrofit.buildService(APIS::class.java)
    val call = request.sentUser("09119907254", "654321" )

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<User> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "response was  Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
             }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: whats the error?